# Object assign on immediately created object when spread

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a bit tired of passing react props this way

```
<Comp one={one} two={two} three={three} />
```

So I started doing

```
<Comp {...{one, two, three}} />
```

However I realized that this computes to Object assig

```
react.createElement(Comp , Object.assign({
    one: one,
    two: two
  }, {
    __source: {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 95
    },
```

Since I'm spreading an object that I'm just creating I expected the compiler/transpiler to be smart enough to realize about that and do something like this instead

```
react.createElement(Comp ,{
    one: one,
    two: two,
    __source: {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 95
    },
```

Is there any Babel plugin to accomplish this, or any way of compiling this way ?

Regards

Comment: What’s wrong with Object.assign?

Comment: Wouldnt `{ one, two, tree }` work at that point?, `{...` literally just does object.assign under the hood

Comment: ^nvm i guess react doesnt like that

Comment: @MattAft the outermost braces are JSX template notations, not object literal braces, that’s why it doesn’t work.

Comment: @Danielo515 What Babel settings are you using?

Comment: @Nathan the default ones of create react app

Comment: @BenSteward there is nothing wrong with it when it makes sense. But when there is no need for it is just overhead

Answer (score 0):

The Babel version and settings you use are pretty important.

Using the latest, I had this code:

```
return (<Child {...{ name: this.name }} />);
```

Which turned into this:

```
return Object(m.a)(t, e), Object(c.a)(t, [{
    key: "render",
    value: function() {
        return o.a.createElement(k, {
            name: this.name
        })
    }
}])
```

Comment: Indeed, but what is the point? Is there any particular configuration that does what I want?